# Azure app service scale out and changes in application gateway

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I am using azure application gateway and azure app service. I have enabled scale out in app service. I have added app service private ip address to application gateway, Will it changes during scale out ? Will it created another app service or the service itself handle the load balancing?

Answer (score 0):

***A scale-out operation is comparable to making several copies of your website and adding load balancing to divide the load among them. There is no need to configure load balancing separately when scale out appear in Azure app since this is already provided by the platform***

In azure app service scale out as increasing number of instances, the more number of instances the application will able to process the user request very smoothly and you need to worry about the load balancing azure will take care of load distributing among the instances

- when number of scaled-out instances actions in single ip address if the last app in a resource group and region combination has been altered, deleted, the deployment unit is recreated it may change.

For your Reference :

[How IP addresses work in App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips)